# Can't use IIS Express in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-express

I have VS 2010 and for some reason I dont have the option "[use iis express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ourjB.png)" when I right click on my website project.

I have installed IIS Express.

The win7 system is up-to-date.

when I go to tools -> options, I don't see the web options.

any idea?

Comment: Did you install IIS Express before VS 2010?

Comment: do you have VS 2010 SP1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need VS 2010 sp1 to use 'IIS Express' with Visual Studio. Please check if you have VS 2010 SP1 installed or not.